# How can I convert an unnamed function to a named one?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made the function below. Basically, if a player types /port and the name of another player the function returns true, I believe.

```
    mp.players.forEach(_player => {
        if(_player.name === name)
            return true;
    });
```

I want to name the function above so I can do something like:

```
if (functionName) [code]
```

So, how can I name  the function above? Or is there any other way to check if it's true. I'm trying to list it on the try...catch statement below:

```
try {
        if (player.adminLevel < 8)  throw "Error 1";
        if (!targetPlayer) throw "Error 2";
        if (player.adminLevel <= targetAdminLevel) throw "Error 3";
        //AND THE NEW ONE HERE
        if (functionName) throw "Error 4";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just write it as a normal function, then pass the function name instead of the lambda expression.

```
function myFunction(player) {
    if(_player.name === name)
        return true;
}


mp.players.forEach(myFunction);
```

Now you can use `myFunction` elsewhere by its name... no "conversion" necessary.

Comment: I realize you just retained the code from the question but that callback is semantically a noop when passed to `forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

You have not created any function. *forEach* is a named function for Array prototype which you are invoking for your array. You can either directly write the *forEach* logic in your try block, or declare a named function and use it like below:

```
    function functionName(players, name){
            return players.some(_player => _player.name === name);
        };


    try {
           if (player.adminLevel < 8)  throw "Error 1";
           if (!targetPlayer) throw "Error 2";
           if (player.adminLevel <= targetAdminLevel) throw "Error 3";
           //AND THE NEW ONE HERE
           if (functionName(mp.players, player.name)) throw "Error 4";
     }
```